# Modifying user in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, debian

I'm looking at some code that has been used to deploy a server, it reads as follows:

```
# User
adduser --system --no-create-home --disabled-login --disabled-password test
adduser test testgroup
chown -R test:testgroup /var/www/test
chmod -R g+w /var/www/test
```

It seems like there is some duplication here. I know I need the first line to create the user, then the second line adds the user to the group, but then if that is the case, is the last line not redundant this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last line may or may not be redundant, depending on the existing permissions for `/var/www/test`.

```
chown -R test:testgroup /var/www/test
```

This sets the owner of `/var/www/test` to be the `test` user, and the group to be `testgroup`. However, we don't know the permissions of this directory. To ensure that it is writable by the new user, this command changes the permissions of the folder, adding write permissions for any user in the `testgroup` group:

```
chmod -R g+w /var/www/test
```

So now we know that `/var/www/test` is set up to allow writes from the newly created user. These permissions *may* have already been there, but the script does not know this.